# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException on value attribute of custom tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have defined a custom tag like below:

```
<ui:composition>
  <h:panelGroup>
     <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="#{id_prefix}#{fieldId}"
            value="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).label}" 
            rendered="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).visible}"/>

        <p:selectOneRadio id="#{id_prefix}#{fieldId}"
            value="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).value}"
            rendered="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).visible}"
            disabled="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).disabled}"
            partialSubmit="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).items}" />
            <p:ajax disabled="#{not validate}" partialSubmit="true"
                update="#{update}"
                process="#{not empty process ? process : '@this'}"
                listener="#{backingBean.validate(fieldId)}" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <tas:helpButton backingBean="#{backingBean}" fieldId="#{fieldId}" />

    </h:panelGrid>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

The attributes like `fieldId` and `backingBean` are set when I use the custom tag on my xhtml view:

```
<tas:radio backingBean="#{nppFormProcessor}" 
     fieldId="deckungskonzept" 
     validate="true" update="generalFields" />
```

The backing bean has a method `getField(String fieldId)` that returns and instance of `Field` class.

On tomcat 7 with MyFaces 2.2.3 it works fine. I want to deploy the code on WebSphere Libery Profile which appears to have a build-in feature for JSF 2.2.

When I run the code on WebSphere, I get the following excetption:

```
    /WEB-INF/lib/platform.jar/META-INF/custom-tags/radio.xhtml at line 36 and column 26 value="#{backingBean.getField(fieldId).value}": Property 'getField' not found on type mypackage.FormProcessor_$_javassist_2 
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit._SharedRendererUtils.findUIOutputConverter(_SharedRendererUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIOutputConverter(RendererUtils.java:407)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getConvertedUISelectOneValue(RendererUtils.java:747)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRadioRendererBase.getConvertedValue(HtmlRadioRendererBase.java:364)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectoneradio.SelectOneRadioRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectOneRadioRenderer.java:41)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:664)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:596)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:277)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:550)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:207)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:773)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1051)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:793)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1051)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:793)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1051)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:793)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1051)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:290)
    .....
    ....
```

Comment: Try to rename your method getField to displayField for example. Because getField can be interpreted like a getter...

Comment: Renaming the method has no effect. Same exception as before. I think the problem is related to rvalue vs. lvalue method expression, and how they are handled in Myfaces 2.2.3 and Myfaces implementation in WebSphere.